# Como descobrir a classe que chamou um método de outra classe?

Tags: java

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de pegar a classe que chamou um método dentro desse método. Por exemplo:

```
public class A {
    public void metodoA() {
        B.metodoB();
    }
}

public static B {
    public void metodoB() {
        //Aqui, de alguma forma, pegar a classe A, quando ela chamar
    }
}
```

Existe essa possibilidade em Java ou eu precisaria enviar a classe como parâmetro para o `metodoB`?

Comment: `B.metodoB(this.getClass());` ?

Comment: @Articuno como eu finalizei na pergunta, essa é a única forma? Não teria como eu já pegar de dentro do `metodoB`?

Comment: Qual versão do Java? Tem a [JEP-259](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259) no Java 9.

Comment: @Renan É a versão 8

Comment: Provavelmente você quer que tenha comportamentos diferentes para cada chamador.
Procure pelos padroes strategy e hook method
Um dos dois ou os dois juntos devem resolver seu problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem uma maneira fácil de fazer isso. Já que o metodo não se importa em saber quem chamou, mas você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
public class A {
    public void metodoA() {
        B.metodoB();
    }
}

public static B {
    public void metodoB() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement element = stackTrace[2];
        System.out.println("O metodo que me chamou: " + element.getMethodName());
        System.out.println("O metodo esta na classe: " + element.getClassName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é possível mesmo se a classe A chamar um `Thread.start()`?

Comment: Sim. Funciona da mesma maneira.